# need platform independent alternative to ItemGroup and PropertyGroup in msbuild .proj file

Tags: msbuild, mono, xbuild

I am porting a visual studio project to mono develop. I have a fairly complex
post-build script in a .proj file, which copies various groups of files into the distribution
folder. Can anyone suggest a suitable alternative to this for linux? I tried xbuild,
but it doesn't support itemgroup and propertygroup.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to extend xbuild to support them,

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3055

It is a known bug for a long time (> 6 months). Someone may implement it and submit the patch to Mono team.

NAnt was a possible alternative, but I don't think it worth the while to rewrite your MSBuild scripts to NAnt scripts.